# What happens when I delete magento product?

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product

I want to delete some disabled configurable products in magento-1.7,I need to know if the deleting affects any statistics like sales,billing and order history.. etc.

Answer (score 2):

> If you want to delete disabled configurable products,It's does not
>   affects any statistics like sales,billing and order history.. etc.

Comment: Hi
It will not affect any statistics. Orders, shipment, credit memo are not affected by the deleting item.

Comment: I mean the statistics of the products I am going to delete, won't be deleted too?

Comment: @EmanSha3ban, If you delete  the statistics of the disabled configurable products like sales,billing and order history.. etc. It will be affects on sale report,Lifetime Sales,Average Orders etc..if order has completed. So please don't delete the  the statistics of the same product...only disabled configurable products.